# Intellij IDEA 2023 unusably slow on non-M1 Mac

Tags: java, macos, performance, intellij-idea, downgrade

I am using a 2019 MacBook Pro and have been a long-time user of IntelliJ IDEA. However, the 2023 version is extremely slow when attempting to perform any task. I have tried increasing the heap size to 4GB and 8GB, but IntelliJ still uses more than 1000% of the CPU and runs out of memory. After reverting back to version 2022.3.3, it runs smoothly with a 2GB heap size, and I can quickly close project windows and type smoothly in the terminal while a project window is starting.

Is there anything I can do to improve the performance of the newer version? I don't want to remain on 2022 indefinitely. Since the issue is unclear, I am unsure how to look for relevant YouTrack tickets.

Comment: Do you have an external monitor attached? I have seen recent issues with several other Jetbrains products when I have a high def monitor plugged into my M2 Mackbook. Just wondering if there is a similar problem with x86 macs.

Comment: Performance problems could be very specific depending on each case. I'd recommend you contact JetBrains support at at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new and provide diagnostic data as per https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235-Reporting-performance-problems

Comment: Same issue on my mac book pro 2019, I tried both Intellij IDEA 2023.1.4 and 2023.2.  When it run some tasks (e.g. building or indexing) my mac is very slow and I almost cannot do anything. But when I switch back to Intellij 2022.3.2, everything goes well.

Comment: I update on this? I am having the same issues. Typing and everything else lags badly

Comment: I have the same issue as well. I did try contacting support at one time, but they were requesting so many information, and the conversation goes back and forth. It was too complex and took too long so I gave up and downgrade.

Comment: Same issue on MacBook Pro 2017 Touch Bar. Had to switch back to 2022.3.2

Comment: Just found this question as facing similar issues on 2023.2.x - have installed 2022.2.5 and it's like greased lightning in comparison.  I can't afford an M1 Macbook - so will stick for now with this version.

Comment: @DavidVictor which macOS version are you running? I'm still on Catalina, but will soon upgrade to Ventura. Was hoping that would solve the problem for me...

Comment: hopefully we get a fix for this in the 2024.1 release: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-745

Comment: apparently disabling the Metal rendering framework for the IDE fixes the issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-326858/2023.2-IDE-UI-Stutters-Every-Second-on-macOS-10.15.  Fix from Jacky Liu: "add the following string into **Help | Edit Custom VM Options**: `-Dsun.java2d.metal=false` then restart IDE"  ...haven't tried this myself yet because it would be too disruptive to change IDE versions right now.  will update once i've finished a few projects and have some time to test

Answer (score -3):

Please Tell the detailed version number of the IntelliJ IDEA.

I'm work fine both in M1 and Intel MacBook Pro.

IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1 Preview -> Build: 231.8109.175

Each version of IntelliJ IDEA has macOs dmg for Intel and macOs Apple Silicon dmg for the M1.
Make sure do not install the wrong dmg.